# Can I script the VM settings for VMware workstation pro 15?

Tags: windows-10, vmware, vmware-workstation

i'm a software engineer and we currently work with development Vm's.
Generally we create incremental VMwares for operating versions and different vendor software versions.
E.g. our Vm repository looks like so:

```
VM01_V01_WinXp-Basic
VM01_V02_WinXp-Basic
VM02_V02_WinXp-Basic-Sdkv03
VM03_V02_Win10-Basic
VM04_V02_Win10-Basic-Sdkv11-SqlServer14
VM04_V03_Win10-Basic-Sdkv11-SqlServer15
VM04_V04_Win10-Basic-Sdkv12-SqlServer15
```

Etc. The naming convention is somewhat confusing but that is not something I came up with.

Now each time I create a new VM I build off an older VM or I create a new VM all together starting with installing windows etc.

Additionally colleagues tend to change the vm's without fully understanding the implications of some settings, this is mostly their network configuration.

For both these issues I'd like to be able to script the settings of a VM.
In short i'd like to define the following settings for cpu, network adapters etc. and then be able to apply these settings with the press of a button (or execution of command ofcourse).

[image]

Doing this from either the guest or host would be okay. Preferably from within the guest - but that seems to be difficult.

Answer (score 1):

1. VM configuration that can be changed from within the guest is *very* limited.  Allowing general VM configuration would break host/guest isolation and would be a security hole.
2. You should be able to automate GUI interaction with any of a number of Windows automation tools.  All widgets are Win32 controls, so you can easily call `GetWindowText` on them to read their labels and identify them.  Of course, be aware that tweaks to the widget text are likely to break your automation. (Most of the control IDs used by VMware Workstation Pro/Player on Windows are not fixed and are dynamically generated; do not rely on them.)
3. For your case, it might be simpler to make scripts that automatically generate the desired `.vmx` files directly or that make changes to an existing one.

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to help me out. Yeah i get what you're saying. Anyways i was hoping for some kind of api or something along those lines. I like your idea of editing the .vmx files directly and i think that that will be what it comes down to.